# Printing the name of each file with certain extension

Tags: linux, bash, foreach

how can I print out the name of each file in a certain directory with a specific extension?

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR="~/Desktop"
SUFFIX="in"

for file in $DIR/*.$SUFFIX
do
    if [ -f $file ]; then
    echo $file
    fi  
done
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Testing whether the file exists after it has been listed seems pointless.

Answer (score 6):

In your DIR="~/Desktop" the "~" not expanded, because it is in "".
remove the "". DIR=~/Desktop

Comment: And furthermore, do **use double quotes around variable substitutions**: `for file in "$DIR"/*."$SUFFIX"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use find with `-type f`

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="~/Desktop"
SUFFIX="in"
find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.${SUFFIX}" -exec somecommand {} \;
```

Comment: The foreach-strucure is a preparation/test. Lateron the file is supposed to be passed to a jar file as an argument

Answer (score 0):

For your information: "file" in Unix systems is typically the name of a command.

Its purpose is to analyze the files given as argument and infer the format. Example:

```
$ file entries.jar 
entries.jar: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for file in `ls $DIR/*.$SUFFIX`
```

Note the `ls` and backticks

Comment: It says: ls: cannot access ~/Desktop/*.in: No such file or directory

Comment: It's not expanding the `~` - use the actual full path or don't put `~/Desktop` in quotes.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Your advice is exactly backwards. Your code is equivalent to `for file in "$DIR"/*."$SUFFIX"`, except that your code breaks with all kinds of characters in file names, and the right way always works.